# Можно ли переопредилить действие аппаратной кнопки "назад"

Tags: java, android

В телефонах samsung есть кнопка "Назад" или в случае Nexus те же самые кнопки, но рисованные. Вопрос: можно ли как то переопредилить действие нажатия на эту кнопку в моем приложении , что  бы к примеру избавить пользователя возможности перейти на предыдущий экран с помощью аппаратной кнопки "назад"?

Comment: для вашего приложения - можно. Для системы - нельзя. Уточните, что вы хотите сделать, а не как вы хотите это сделать.

Comment: Хочу при нажатии на аппаратную кнопку "назад"  -  хочу блокировать это нажатие!

Comment: Вы не сможете ничего с этим сделать вне вашего приложения. Я еще раз повторюсь: Напишите, зачем вам это нужно. Часто есть более легкий и правильный способ, чем тот, что вы придумали, и пытаетесь реализовать, но всеравно не знаете, как

Comment: Мне именно в приложении и надо... способ ниже работает

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Да, в Activity переопределите

```
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
```

Comment: если оставить этот метод пустым - получится что  кнопка назад - не перебросит меня на предыдущее активити

Comment: Верно. super.onBackPressed(); и вызывает действие возврата.

Comment: понял, работает!